# How do i access and read avro file using http linked service in azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to read avro file located in internet location using azure data factory copy activity. I tried creating pipeline with httplinked service and source dataset as avro, i am getting following error message

*Http request failed with client error, status code 404 NotFound, please check your activity settings. If you configured a baseUrl that includes path, please make sure it ends with '/'.*

In the linkedservice i  gave url that i was able to access the avro file using Chrome;but while previewing data  i am getting this error.
The test connection is successful butpreview data fails. Do we have any documentation how do access the avro file using copy activity of adf.
I tried Microsoft documentation but this comes with very little clarity.